# Is it possible to get time_point from zoned_time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I tried to get local time / UTC selectively in `std::string`.

1. What I've tried:

(1) getting `std::string` for UTC works fine with `std::format`:

```
auto utc = std::chrono::system_clock::now(); 
std::string sTime = std::format("{:%H%M%S}", utc);
```

(2) and local time:

```
auto zoned = std::chrono::zoned_time{ "Asia/Seoul", std::chrono::system_clock::now() }; 
sTime = std::format("{:%H%M%S}", zoned);
```

2. What I want to achieve:

But they have different types. How can I achieve a functionality like this?

```
bool b = true;
sTime = std::format("{:%H%M%S}", b? utc : zoned);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoned_time` has two getters:

```
.get_sys_time()    // get the utc time
.get_local_time()  // get the local time
```

It can do this because `zoned_time` is just a convenience data structure that holds `{time_zone const*, sys_time}`.  If you ask it for the `sys_time`, it just returns what it has.  If you ask it for the `local_time`, it uses the `time_zone` to change the `sys_time` into `local_time`.

And if you format a `zoned_time` then it formats local time.

So:

```
auto zoned = std::chrono::zoned_time{ "Asia/Seoul", std::chrono::system_clock::now() }; 
std::string sTime;
if (b)
    sTime = std::format("{:%H%M%S}", zoned.get_sys_time());
else
    sTime = std::format("{:%H%M%S}", zoned);
```

Or wrap that up in a function for a one-liner:

```
auto choose_time = [](bool b, auto zoned)
{
    if (b)
        return std::format("{:%H%M%S}", zoned.get_sys_time());
    return std::format("{:%H%M%S}", zoned);
};

bool b = true;
auto zoned = std::chrono::zoned_time{ "Asia/Seoul", std::chrono::system_clock::now() }; 
auto sTime = choose_time(b, zoned);
```

### Update

[@starriet주녕차](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10027592/starriet-%EC%A3%BC%EB%85%95%EC%B0%A8) makes a good observation in a comment below that when you want local time in `choose_time` that `zoned` is "good enough" as opposed to `zoned.get_local_time()`.

And in this particular example, the two are equivalent.  However I thought it worthwhile to point out when `zoned` is actually a superior choice:

**If** the format specification asks for time zone abbreviation (`%Z`) or time zone offset (`%z`), then `zoned` (which has type `zoned_time`) has this information and can can supply it, and `zoned.get_local_time()` (which has type `local_time`) does not.

Additionally `zoned.get_sys_time()` can also format `%Z` (as "UTC") or `%z` (as "0000"). The type of `zoned.get_sys_time()` is `sys_time` and has the semantics of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Whereas `local_time` has the semantics of:  It is a local time which has yet to be paired with a `time_zone`.  And `zoned_time` is effectively that pairing.

Comment: for future myself) See [`std::formatter<std::chrono::zoned_time>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/zoned_time/formatter) and other related pages to get the hint why just `zoned` is enough instead of `zoned.get_local_time()` when formatting local time.

Comment: Good comment.  I've updated my answer to explore this choice a little further.